# Testing a jsonwebtoken authentication express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently learning to do testing in general and I am not sure how one tests an express middleware that authenticates a jsonwebtoken. An express middleware is basically a function so in theory it should be unit testable. Could someone show me how one would do so? Here is my middleware so far. I am currently using mocha and chai as my testing framework.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import secret from "../jwtSecret"

function authenticateJwt(req, res, next){
  let token;
  let authorizationHeaders = req.headers["authorization"];
  if(authorizationHeaders){
    token = authorizationHeaders.split(" ")[1];
  }
  if(token) {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decodedToken) => {
      if(err){
        res.status(403).json({
          success: false,
          error: "Invalid token provided"
        });
      } else {
        next();  
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({
      success: false,
      error: "No token provided"
    });
  }
}

export default authenticateJwt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, by testing the input and output you could test a function. In this case, req/res/next is the input. But instead of `return`, `res.status(403).json()` and `next()` comes as the result of your middleware(or output).

So by mocking req/res/next, you will be at full control of the input and output. As follow.

```
describe('middleware/auth', ()=> {
  let mockReq = {
    headers:{} // your JWT here
  }
  let mockRes = {
    status = function(code){return 'status${code}'}
  }
  let nextCalled = false;
  let next = function(){nextCalled = true}

  it('should pass on right jwt',()=>{
    mockReq.headers['JWT'] = 'right jwt'
    authenticateJwt(mockReq, mockRes, next)
    expect(nextCalled).to.be.true;
  })
})
```

But using additional variables like nextCalled is not the best choice. [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) or other spies might be better.

Comment: So what libraries should I be using to test this functionality? Currently only using mocha as my test runner and chai for assertions. I don't really want to have to learn another library like Sinon. Is it possible to test current functionality without these libraries?

Comment: I didn't use sinon in my example, so of course you can just test it that way. Spies like sinon provide make it easier to check whether a function is called, like the next() in my example. But free fine to use just mocha and chai at first.